# Typescript. Как импортировать типы(type) из внешних файлов *d.ts

Tags: angular2, typescript, типы

Подскажите пожалуйста как импортировать типы из внешних файлов *d.ts, не получается разбить index.d.ts на несколько файлов.

Структура такая:

```
types
   |--custom
      |--index.d.ts
      |--task.d.ts
```

В index.d.ts:

```
import { Task } from ‘./task’;
type Project = {
    title: string;
    tasks?: Task[];
};
```

В task.d.ts:

```
export type Task = {
    title: string;
};
```

Когда использую обычный es6 синтаксис отваливаются все типы(

Comment: `task.d.ts` и `import ... from ‘./task’;` - почему?

Comment: Почему без расширения? В rxjs и angular2 вроде везде без расширения импорт.

Comment: попробуйте убрать `./` из `./task` - заработает ли?

Comment: Если не использовать `./` то это будет не относительный путь, поиск будет в node_modules/@types